# Dav SVN apache mod not working in Ubuntu trusty when there are spaces in the url

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, subversion, webdav

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS with subversion 1.8.8 and attempting to set up remote svn access via apache2 with mod_dav_svn - this is a migration to linux from a windows server running apache2.

The issue I am having is that any `<location>` with a space in its name will not work, the below example will work:

```
<Location "/svn/Test_Repository" >

    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "/media/windowsshare/TortoiseSVN-Repo-Store/Test Repository"
    SVNListParentPath On

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
    Require valid-user

    SVNIndexXSLT "/repos-web/view/repos.xsl"

</Location>
```

However when I replace the underscore in the location with a space to make it `<Location "/svn/Test Repository" >` I get a 403 forbidden error with the following in the error log:

```
[Tue Apr 21 14:46:34.991584 2015] [dav:error] [pid 30873] [client 192.168.20.5:63935] Could not fetch resource information.  [403, #0], referer: http://192.168.20.12/svn/
[Tue Apr 21 14:46:34.991597 2015] [dav:error] [pid 30873] [client 192.168.20.5:63935] The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001], referer: http://192.168.20.12/svn/
```

The directory `/media/windowsshare/TortoiseSVN-Repo-Store/` is mounted with www-data having both user and group ownership.

What could be causing this, and how do I go about fixing it? I have spent the best part of six hours searching and experimenting with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is a reported bug as you can see here:
[Ubuntu bug-launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1284641)

As you can see in the Bug-Track-Comment, the Bug has been fixed for apache2, but has not been added to the Ubuntu repo yet:

> John Pye (jdpipe) wrote on 2014-09-04:    #9
>   This bug is resolved by modifying a new 14.04 server to install the
>   apache2 packages from
>   https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5, ie
>
> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 sudo apt-get update sudo
>   apt-get dist-upgrade
>
> Worked for me... the new Apache2 packages should be urgently included
>   in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, since users upgrading their Subversion servers
>   will inevitably have horrible problems.

Note: I could not proof it yet! Just could check with Ubuntu 12